# React Native Firebase Set Up

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to grab data from my firebase DB within my react native application.

I have it set up correctly (as far as I can see) but when the application renders I don't see any data.

I have a component **FirebaseList.js**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  **Details**
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const data = [];

class FirebaseList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      listViewData: data,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List
      dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
      renderRow={data =>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>{data}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I call this component elsewhere - my export is set up correctly as are my imports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling `this.state = {
      listViewData: data,
    };`, but are not setting `data` anywhere.

Comment: Do I need to assign a request to fetch from the DB to data? As I defined data just above my component declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch data from firebase in componentDidMount()!

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';
class FirebaseList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      listViewData: [],
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const firebaseConfig = {
    **Details**
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('/path/datas/').once('value', snapshot => {
      const dataArray = [];
      const yourDatas = snapshot.val();
      for(let data in yourDatas){
        dataArray.push(data)
      }
      this.setState({ listViewData: dataArray });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List
      dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
      renderRow={data =>
        <ListItem>
          <Text>{data}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, using this code and referencing my database with `.ref(/signposts)` I cannot see any of my data on render.

Comment: have you tried `.ref('signposts')`? You should try `console.log(snapshot.val())` if data exist you probably wrong data handling. if data doesn't exit maybe path is wrong or data doesn't exit.

Comment: I figured out that it was my rule settings, I wasn't allowing read permissions from my database without authentication. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad to hear that. for more information .once()'s third parameter is error callback. you can handle error occasion.